# JPA different sorting result with Criteria API and native SQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, blaze-persistence

I use JPA with Hibernate for the data access in PostgreSQL.

I need to sort `Reviews` list by count of ReviewLikes with `positive=true`. But when I try to get Reviews list (include all relations) with sorting and pagination I see different results with Criteria API and native SQL query.
If I use native SQL - sorting works fine.
If I use Criteria API returns wrong result. Sorting is done, but not completely, some elements are out of order.

Also I tried to use Blaze persistence, but unsuccessfully.

I suspect that the error is somewhere in my criteria, but I have been trying for the 4th day to find at least some similar case and without success.

Project has 4 entities:

1. **WebResource**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "web_resource")
public class WebResource {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
    private String id;

    private String url;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "resource_type")
    private ResourceType resourceType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private WebResource parent;
}
```

2. **Review**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reviews")
public class Review {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "resource_id")
    private String resourceId;

    @Column(name = "review_id")
    private String reviewId;

    private Byte rating;

    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resource_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private WebResource webResource;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "review", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ReviewLike> likes;
}
```

3. **User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "avatar_file_name")
    private String avatarFileName;

    @Column(name = "email_confirmed")
    private Boolean emailConfirmed;
}
```

3. **ReviewLike**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reviews_likes")
public class ReviewLike {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "review_id")
    private String reviewId;

    private Boolean positive;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "review_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Review review;
}
```

I tried native SQL, and it works fine (ordering right):

```
select review.*
from reviews review
         join web_resource webResource on review.resource_id = webResource.id
         left join reviews_likes reaction on review.id = reaction.review_id
         join users u on review.user_id = u.id
group by review.id, webResource.url, webResource.resource_type
order by sum(case when reaction.positive = true then 1 else 0 end) DESC
limit 10 offset 0;
```

But JPA Criteria API (Spring specification) returns list with wrong order:

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

SetJoin<Review, ReviewLike> reviewLikeJoin = reviewRoot.joinSet(Review_.LIKES);
Expression<?> sortExpression sortExpression = criteriaBuilder.sum(
    criteriaBuilder.<Integer>selectCase()
    .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(reviewLikeJoin.get(ReviewLike_.POSITIVE), true), 1)
    .otherwise(0)
);

criteriaQuery.groupBy(reviewRoot.get(Review_.ID));
criteriaBuilder.desc(sortExpression);
```

Blaze persistence doesn't work correctly too:

```
CriteriaBuilder<Review> criteriaBuilder = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, Review.class, "review")
            .leftJoinFetch("review.likes", "reviewLike")
            .leftJoinFetch("review.webResource", "webResource")
            .leftJoinFetch("review.user", "user")
            .groupBy("review.id", "review.likes.reviewId", "review.likes.id")
            .orderByDesc("SUM(case when reviewLike.positive = true then 1 else 0 end)");

List<Review> reviews = criteriaBuilder.getResultList();
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Can you please also post the SQL queries that are generated when executing the JPA Criteria query or the Blaze-Persistence query?

Comment: Also show all the code you use to execute the Criteria api query. Just calling criteriaBuilder.desc creates an expression but it won't get that added to the query, which might be why you don't see ordering. You need to explicitly add it to the query using criteriaQuery.orderBy

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was not in Criteria API, but in the bad logic of SQL query which I expected. I refactored expected SQL query and I was able to implement it in the Criteria API.

Example for right SQL logic:

```
select e, (select count(*) from r.likes l where l.positive = true) as likeCount
from Review r
join fetch r.thing
join fetch r.user
left join fetch r.likes
order by likeCount desc
```